# office.js displayDialogAsync could not work with displayInIframe: true

Tags: typescript, office-js

when I tried to use the displayDialogAsync Under typescript/react as:

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(tIframeUrl, { height: 85, width: 99, displayInIframe: true }, asyncResult => {
  dialog = asyncResult.value;
  window.addEventListener("message", messageHandler, false);
});
```

I get:

```
asyncResult = OSF_DDA_AsyncResult {
    value: undefined, 
    status: "failed", 
    error: OSF_DDA_Error
}

An internal error has occurred. 5001
```

When I set the flag to `false` it is working fine. Can you suggest me a solution?

Comment: Which "flag" are you referring too?

Comment: I assume that you are using Office Online. What operating system and browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Getting the same error if I close the dialog once and then re-open it via add-in. I used it with displayInIframe: true, while it's working fine with this flag set to false.

Using via Outlook add-in on google chrome Version 66.0.3359.181, on Mac OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.6 (15G18013)

Result of the api call is failed with result.error: {\\"name\\":\\"Internal Error\\",\\"message\\":\\"An internal error has occurred.\\",\\"code\\":5001}